# .XResources are not loaded automatically. - Where should I put my xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources initialisation?

Tags: x11, xinit

I added an `.Xresources` file to my home directory and when I load it from my shell prompt with `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` the resource settings are recognized (for X programs started afterwards).

However I would like to have these resources applied all the time when i login to my user account. I *thought* the X11 system would look for the `~/.Xresources` file by default, but it doesn't.

The machine runs CentOS 6 and I connect to it remotely from MobaXterm (MS Windows) which provides a X server and shows the windows of each CentOS app in MS Windows windows.

So where do I put the merge command best? Shell initialization or `~/.xinitrc`? Or somewhere else?

Comment: It entirely depends on the rest of your setup. I use `xdm`, which executes an `.xsession` in the user's home directory when the user logs in, and that's where my `xrdb` command sits. But that's the old-fashioned way, many "modern desktop" display managers don't respect X conventions.  I am sure CentOS also allows to install different display managers, and I have no idea what the default is. So find out which it is, and read the docs.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! - I’m not using a window manager or display manager on the CentOS machine. I connect to it remotely from MobaXterm (MS Windows) which provides a X server and shows the windows of each CentOS app in MS Windows windows. But still the `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` comamdn i run on the CentOS machine, so I thought the some default laoding would happen on that machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resources are stored on the X server. So if you are using a remote X server on Windows, the best way would be to copy your `.Xresources` file to Windows, and load it into the X server whenever you start the X server.

If this doesn't work for you, because you want to have your `.Xresources` on the CentOS machine, then the only way to do it would be to check on every login, e.g. inside `.profile`. Make sure to also check `DISPLAY`, and all call `xrdb` if `DISPLAY` is set. It's also nice to have some sort of check to make sure this only gets called when you are logging in remotely. Finally, if you have several connections at once, you may want to use `xrdb` first to see if the resources are already loaded, and only load them when they are missing.

---

The X resources are **used** by the X clients (application programs, but probably not your MobaXTerm, which is Windows), but they are **stored** on the X server.

So when you run `xrdb`, it connects to the X server like all X clients do, and makes changes to the stored value.

If the X server used is running is on your windows machine (no matter if it's provided by MobaXTerm, or if it's some other X server running on Windows, like VcXsrv), then that's where the resources are.

I had a quick look at the MobaXTerm documentation, but it's not obvious how to access the in-built X server locally. Possibly you can do it through a "local terminal" and then use Cygwin or WSL to execute xrdb on your Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks dirkt! Very, very inteersting! I didn't know that the Xresources are used by the X _Server_ (i.e. the local program - heer MobaXterm - merely displaying the app), I thought this is used by the app on the X client (i.e. the machine where the whole OS runs - here CentOS). - This means that `xrdb` (which runs in a shell on the _client_) sends the merge details to the server???